# SonarRunner Failing in Java 8

Tags: gradle, java-8, sonarqube, findbugs

I have a java project with build system as Gradle. Recently we migrated to Java 8. After this migration sonarRunner task started failing with the following error :

```
05:10:51.823 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3...
05:10:56.502 INFO  - Findbugs output report: /pathtoproject/build/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
The following errors occurred during analysis:
  Unable to get XClass for java/util/function/BiConsumer
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1792
```

I started googling it and found out Findbugs 2.0.3 does not support I need to upgrade it and it was recommended that I should use Sonar server 5.x.x (my current sonar server is 5.4.x). I have some constraints yet I want my sonarRunner to be successful. Here are my constraints :

1. I can not upgrade the sonar server version (not in my hand)
2. Can not downgrade Java version.

I tried to search how to just upgrade the findbugs version in SonarRunner plugin that also I could not find. Please help me.

Comment: The fact that your SonarQube is trying to run FindBugs 2.0.3 leads me to assume your SonarQube Java Plugin is out of date. You should be using at least FindBugs 3.x for Java 8 support. Talk to the SonarQube admin to get a FindBugs plugin upgrade.

Comment: can't I write anything in my gradle scripts to make sonar use some other version of FindBugs ?

Comment: At least how do I make sonar not to run FindBugs as I don't even need it. Is there a way to exclude a plugin.

Comment: The version is set by the SonarQube admin, but you may try setting `sonar.preview.excludePlugins` to `findbugs` (excludes a plugin from preview analysis). If other plugins must also be excluded: That's a comma-separated list. The FindBugs plugin has no general off switch unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Md, you can delete/move the findbugs plugin(sonar-findbugs-plugin-x.x.jar) from $SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins and restart the server.This will uninstall the findbugs from SQ